# How to programmatically replicate a request found in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, python, http, firefox-developer-tools, google-developer-tools

I'm looking at my balance on [Venmo.com](https://venmo.com/account/settings/balance) but they only show you 3 months at a time and I'd like to get my entire transaction history.

Looking at the Chrome Developer Tools, under the network tab, I can see the request to `https://api.venmo.com/v1/transaction-history?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-01-31` which returns JSON.

I'd like to programmatically iterate through time and make several request and aggregate all of the transactions. However, I keep getting 401 Unauthorized.

My initial approach was just using Node.js. I looked at the cookie in the request and copied it into a `secret.txt` file and then sent the request:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import fs from 'fs-promise'

async function main() {
  try {
    const cookie = await fs.readFile('secret.txt')  
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Cookie': cookie,
      }, 
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.venmo.com/v1/transaction-history?start_date=2016-11-08&end_date=2017-02-08', options)
      console.log(response)
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('please put your cookie in a file called `secret.txt`')
    return
  }
}
```

That didn't work do I tried copying all of the headers over:

```
const cookie = await fs.readFile('secret.txt')  
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': cookie,
    'Host': 'api.venmo.com',
    'Origin': 'https://venmo.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'https://venmo.com/account/settings/balance/statement?end=02-08-2017&start=11-08-2016',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36',
  }, 
}
try {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.venmo.com/v1/transaction-history?start_date=2016-11-08&end_date=2017-02-08', options)
  console.log(response)
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

This also did not work.

I even tried making the request from the console of the website and got a 401:

```
fetch('https://api.venmo.com/v1/transaction-history?start_date=2016-11-08&end_date=2017-02-08', {credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(console.log)
```

So my question here is this: I see a network request in Chrome Developer Tools. How can I make that same request programmatically? Preferably in Node.js or Python so I can write an automated script.

Comment: Chrome lets you copy network requests as `fetch()` calls now.

Comment: If you'd like to add a "Copy as Python (requests)" to your Chrome's Network tab, see this GitHub thread: https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/issues/64#issuecomment-1220330554

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In the Network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools, right click the request and click "Copy" > "Copy as cURL (bash)". You can then either write a script using the curl command directly, or use https://curlconverter.com/ to convert the cURL command to Python, JavaScript, PHP, R, Go, Rust, Elixir, Java, MATLAB, Dart or JSON.

Comment: So... you're recommending that the OP should copy their cookie's secret value into some third-party website?

Comment: @ParthianShot https://curlconverter.com works client-side using JavaScript. Unless the website gets hacked or sold to someone nefarious, the curl commands will never leave your browser. There's also a command-line tool that doesn't make any network calls whatsoever, which you can install with `npm install curlconverter`. Disclaimer: I maintain curlconverter.

Comment: There are a couple of websites that do the same thing as [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) that *do* upload your command to themselves though, such as ReqBin. I would never use them.